# Dynamically limit maximum number of checkboxes selectable

Tags: javascript

I found many scripts to limit max number of checkboxes that can be selected in a page with javascript, for example here is one:

http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/checkbox-limit.php

However I don't need a specific number, but a VARIABLE one.

This means that I need to have a percentage limit instead of just a number.

For example, limit user selection to max 30% of the checkboxes in the page.

Any help on how to achieve this is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To alter that script to be a percentage vs. a fixed total you just need to take 30% of the total number of elements.

```
function chkcontrol(j) {
  var length = document.form1.chb.length;

  // Max number allowed checked is 30% of the total
  var max = Math.round(length * .3);
  var total = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
    if(document.form1.ckb[i].checked){
      total = total + 1;
    }

    if(total > max){
      alert("Please Select only three") 
      document.form1.ckb[j].checked = false ;
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, however I have a problem: the checkbox names that I assigned are "frnd[]" and I should put this names in the js function (I need to keep the parenthesis in the checkbox names to declare in php that they form an array). Will the empty parenthesis be misinterpreted by js? because right now the script is not working!

Comment: just to explain better: here in the code we are using 2 objects which are ckb[i] and ckb[j]. In my code, my object is called frnd[] (it's a php array). I don't think that I can use that one in javascript in place of ckb[i] and ckb[j] because it contains already the parenthesis... could I write something like this: {(frnd[])[i]} and {(frnd[])[j]} or maybe define the object name with an alias? unfortunately I am not familiar with javascript!

Comment: issue solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574509/rename-javascript-object-in-order-to-use-a-php-array