# rename javascript object in order to use a php array

Tags: php, javascript

I never used javascript, but I need it for my project.
I would like to use a php array which is called abc[] inside a javascript function.

Currently the working javascript code is:

```
if(document.form1.checkbox[i].checked)
```

I would like to use the abc[] array instead of checkbox

This doesn't work, because the [] of the php array name mix with the [i] of the javascript code...but it shows what I would like to achieve:

```
if(document.form1.abc[][i].checked)
```

Is it possible to define abc[] as xxx variable in javascript or use any other method to get this working?

```
if(document.form1.xxx[i].checked)
where xxx=abc[]
```

Comment: 1st thing you need to understand is the difference between the client and server side. The client and server are autonomous entities. Generally after server gets the request it sends a string to the client to be processed and then exits. 2nd thing document.form1.checkbox is getting a dom element(object) from the document. So you could print out a string to the client of the name of each checkbox but I think we need to know what your goal is before a good suggestion is made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always access object properties as array like this:

```
document.forms['form1'].elements['abc[]'][i].checked
```

Comment: I like your answer and it seems it would do the job.. but I didn't succeed to get it working! Here is my original code
http://jsbin.com/ejoreg/3/edit#source
Here is the code with your suggestion:
http://jsbin.com/efimil/edit#javascript,html

Comment: `var length = document.forms['form1'].elements['abc[]'][i].length;` - remove `[i]` and it will work as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$abc = array(
...
);

?>

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var checkbox=eval(<?= json_encode( $abc ) ?>);
    ...
</script>
```

Comment: Couple of notes: 1) Using eval() is considered poor practice, there are a number of libraries to decode json that should be used instead (eg http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/); 2) PHP is generally a server-side language and JS is generally a client-side, never the twain shall meet. While injection is possible, as demonstrated above, it would be preferable to create a PHP service with an XML/JSON output that is accessed through AJAX or a similar JS construct.  Injection is ugly and prone to code creep.

Comment: I don't even believe you need to eval it, but may depending on situation. Also (depending on its contents) an `implode` may work as well. `var foo = [<?= implode(',',$abc); ?>];` or `var foo = ['<?= implode("','",$abc); ?>'];`

Comment: You don't even need the eval. PHP executes on the server side, so it will be parsed by the browser anyway. `var checkbox = <?php echo json_encode( $abc ); ?>;` should work.