# How can I limit the maximum number of selected CheckBoxes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

On the page there is a CheckBoxList. I create this:

```
@foreach (var project in Model.Projects)
{
    <input type="checkbox" 
        id="@project.Name"
        name="Projects"
        value="@project.ID"
        title="@project.Name" />
    <label for="@project.Name">@project.Name</label><br/>
}
```

How can I limit the maximum number of selected CheckBoxes?

Comment: Проблема решена вот ссылка:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447344/dynamically-limit-maximum-number-of-checkboxes-selectable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 int count = 1;
 int maxnoofselected = 1;

@foreach (var project in Model.Projects)
{
    if(count <= maxnoofselected)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" 
        id="@project.Name"
        name="Projects"
        value="@project.ID"
        title="@project.Name"
        checked="checked" />
        <label for="@project.Name">@project.Name</label><br/>
        @count++;
    }
    else
    {    
        <input type="checkbox" 
        id="@project.Name"
        name="Projects"
        value="@project.ID"
        title="@project.Name" />
        <label for="@project.Name">@project.Name</label><br/>
    }
}
```

If count is less or equal to maxnoofselected (i.e. your number) then check box will be checked otherwise it will be unchecked.

Comment: This code will generate the 2 selected checkboxes, and other non-selected. It is necessary that the user can select only a limited number of sheets. The solution can be found in the comments to the first post.